# Submit Form should display message after successful submit to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to submit a form to Google Sheets. This step is successful and I am getting all the numbers in the sheet. Now I want to display a success message after the form is submitted and the result from Google Sheets is ok. How do I do it?

I have tried various messages in javascript and ajax, but don't have much understanding about it. I have shown my code below so you can have a look at it.

```html
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
                          <select class="form-control custom-form" name="country_code" id="country_code">
                            <option name="country_code" value="+91">India 91</option>
                            <option name="country_code" value="+93">Afghanistan 93</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group spec-col col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control custom-form" id="phone_no" name="phone_no" placeholder="Enter the Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <button class="btn btn-submit" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

For Submitting the content to Google Sheets, here is the code

```
<script>
      const scriptURL = 'GOOGLE SHEETS URL'
      const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

      form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
          .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
          .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
      })
    </script>
```

After the form is successful, I can see a success message in the console. Instead, I want to show a simple one-word line in HTML, that thanks a lot. Your submission is successful, once the response from Google Sheets is Ok and hide the form.

Edit: The rest of the code can be referenced from here: https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow the button create a blank response message

tag just like this

```
<button class="btn btn-submit" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
<p id="response_message"></p>
```

Now in the scripts make the following change in the fetch function:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    var response_message = document.getElementById("response_message");
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => response_message.innerHTML = "Success!")
      .catch(error => response_message.innerHTML = "Error!")
  })
```

Comment: Google Sheets doesn't add an entry after doing this.

Comment: You're missing closing `)` after `.then`  and `.catch`

Comment: Even after adding it doesn't show the response in the p tag. Also, what can I do to close the form?
Once the form is closed, then I should be able to show the line.

Comment: Also, it shows me the message, x is not defined in the Chrome console.

Comment: Great. It's working now. One small thing, can you tell me, how I can hide the form, and then display the message?

Comment: Add a id to the form tag `<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="google_form">`

And within scripts
change `.then(response => response_message.innerHTML = "Success!")` to
`.then(response => {response_message.innerHTML = "Success!"; document.getElementById("google_form").hide();})`

Also please remember to put the <p> tag outside the form

Comment: I placed the p tag after the form ends, but now it shows me error instead of success, and the form also, isn't hidden.

Comment: The data is submitted to google sheets correctly. just shows the "Error" instead of success. I have also updated the ID in the form.

Comment: I am rewriting the code. Please check if this matches with yours and update that accordingly. For hiding you can also use this:

`form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    var response_message = document.getElementById("response_message");
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => {response_message.innerHTML = "Success!"; document.getElementById("google_form").css("display", "none");})
      .catch(error => response_message.innerHTML = "Error!")
  })`

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, Thanks for your help. In the console, I see an error: Unexpected token var

Comment: Please put a ; after `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: It shows the "Error" message if I put a ; as you have said.

Comment: I made the client understand that keeping the contact form open is a better idea, instead of closing it. Thanks a lot, Utkarsh for all your help.