# How to display a confirmation message after form submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From google sheets script editor, I have created a form using the below codes:

.gs

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()


function doPost (e) {
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
lock.tryLock(10000)

try {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})

sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}

catch (e) {
return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}

finally {
lock.releaseLock()
}
}
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
</style>
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
<input name="text" type="text" placeholder="text" required>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" class="jfk-button jfk-button-action "> 
</form>
<script>
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTGqZqLTAsOpSweMn0xgHP0sOJPsFg5ZShC1HqzVoDoNi5h5Y/exec'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault()
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
 })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When a user submits the form, I receive the data in the sheet successfully but the user does not know that his info have been delivered so I just need to display a confirmation message after form submission, something like "Thank you!"

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit Form should display message after successful submit to Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831426/submit-form-should-display-message-after-successful-submit-to-google-sheets)

Comment: Thank you for your interest Tedinoz. I tried the code mentioned in the link: 

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    var response_message = document.getElementById("response_message");
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => response_message.innerHTML = "Success!")
      .catch(error => response_message.innerHTML = "Error!")
  })

For some reason it gives a syntax error in the .gs

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something that might help in similar situations:

in the .html file add the submit input like this:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" onsubmit="myFunction()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then add the below script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>
```

This will trigger a window at the top of the screen that shows the form was successfully completed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, when making a submit form, it will be sent to submission.html.

> The "input type="submit" defines a submit button that submits all form values to a form-handler. The form-handler is typically a server page with a script for processing the input data. The form-handler is specified in the form's action attribute.